# Best way to return pointer to nested std::vector items

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In the block of code below I would like to refactor so I'm returning an array of three pointers to a vector of doubles. I'm a little confused as the best way to do this.

If the error is hit, i'd also like it to be easy to detect from the calling function.

Do I need to convert the vCase var into something like:

```
std::vector<double>[3] vCases
// or
double[3] vCases
```

Also whats the correct function definition for this? I get the basics of Arrays, the fact i've got a nested vector is whats throwing me!

any help gratefully recieved.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > TrainingCases::getCase(int caseNo) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vCase;
    if (caseNo > vInputs.size()) {
        std::cout << "TrainingCases Error: Out of range caseNo selected. " << std::endl;
        return vCase;
    } else {
        vCase.push_back(vInputs.at(caseNo));
        vCase.push_back(vTargets.at(caseNo));
        vCase.push_back(vScoreModifiers.at(caseNo));
        return vCase;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are vInputs, vTargets, and vScoreModifiers? Do they just contain doubles, or vectors? What is the exact problem you are having? Does this code not compile?

Comment: All those variables are of the type std::vector<double>. Ideally I'd like to return a set of three pointers to those items. The code does compile. But it will be called very often so its in my interest not to make lots of copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure if I get what you want to accomplish... Anyway, the following would certainly work:

```
vector<vector<double>> getCase()
{
    vector<vector<double>> vCase;
    return vCase;
}
```

If you want to kind of return a pointer to an array of vectors, the following would do:

```
vector<double>* getCase()
{
    vector<double>* vCase = new vector<double>[3];
    return vCase;
}
```

But that would be a very bad idea, since you would have to call `delete[]` on the returned pointer somewhere to prevent a memory leak. A better option would be to write

```
struct CaseType
{
    vector<double> vCase[3];
};

CaseType getCase()
{
    CaseType myCase;
    return myCase;
}
```

The point is, you cannot create a temporary stack object inside your function and then return a pointer to it, since it will be automatically destructed. If you create the object using `new` however you will have to free the memory somewhere, and I wouldn't write code like that (in this case).

**Edit**

Judging from you comment, I believe you want something like this:

```
struct CaseType
{
    vector<double> vCase[3];
};

void getCase(CaseType& myCase)
{
    // myCase.vCase[0] = ...
    // myCase.vCase[1] = ...
    // ...
}
```

This way you don't have to construct temporary objects all the time. You would call you function like that:

```
CaseType myCase;
getCase(myCase);
// do stuff with myCase
```

Comment: Thanks, good spot about the var going out of scope. What i'm really trying to get to is that the three vectors I want to point to are going to live longer than anything that calls it. They are going to be read very often and may end up a fair size. Id like to get the three references to these out in one call without creating anything significant. You last answer would work, so I might use something like that.

Comment: I'm not clear because it's vague, but you might be looking for `shared_ptr`

Comment: @joeButler Well in this case, my last approach is a very common way to do that. You just need to have one single object of `CaseType` and pass it by reference. Instead of the `struct`, you could also write `typedef array<vector<double>, 3> CaseType;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a built-in array, mainly because they are not copyable when on themselves (built-in arrays are copyable when they are a member of something). The easiest way may be to return a `std::array<std::vector<double>, 3>` instead:

```
return std::array<std::vector<double>, 3>{ vInputs[caseNo],
                                           vTargets[caseNo],
                                           vScoreModifiers[caseNo] };
```

For the case that the index is out of range I would throw an exception. Of course, if you actually use want to return pointers and the objects stay around long enough, you'd use a slightly modified version:

```
return std::array<std::vector<double> const*, 3>{ &vInputs[caseNo],
                                                  &vTargets[caseNo],
                                                  &vScoreModifiers[caseNo] };
```

The `const` is optional but the things you return sound as if they are not getting modified.

Comment: Thanks, your second answer looks like what I want although it seems like it needs c++11 which i'm not currently compiling against. Is there universal equivalent?

Comment: Well, a simple equivalent of `std::array<T, 3>` is simple to define. If you want to have a variable sized version things become a bit more tricky, though.

Comment: Thanks, will have a go at this.